# Set_radio codeigniter from database [EDIT REGISTRY]

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have following code:

```
 echo form_radio($arr_gen_fem,
              ($btn_value == 'Editar') ? ( isset($row_new_person) ? $row_new_person->gender: set_value('gender')) : '');
```

I need display the value from database for edit registry, but this not display. 
The problem is only with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

try putting your condition result into a variable then add the variable as a param.

```
$result = ($btn_value == 'Editar') ? ( isset($row_new_person) ? $row_new_person->gender: set_value('gender')) : '';
echo form_radio($arr_gen_fem, $result);
```